# Push notification with GCM issue

Tags: android, service, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working on Push Notification application with google cloud messaging from this tutorial: 
[here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)
this is the most best tutorial I've seen.
It's work correctly but I can't implement it to my own project.
it seems that problem occur from `GCMIntentService` . this service runs in app automatically after `GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);` but I don't know how?!
and there is no where that run this service.

so I wonder if some one can explain how I can Implement this to my app and explain how exactly some wired parts works. thanks.

this the activity going to register with google:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // label to display gcm messages
    TextView lblMessage;

    // Asyntask
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

    // Alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Connection detector
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    public static String name;
    public static String email;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if Internet present
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // Getting name, email from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        name = i.getStringExtra("name");
        email = i.getStringExtra("email");      

        // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

        // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
        // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

        lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);

        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

        // Get GCM registration id
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

        Log.i("LOG", "register ID is:"+regId);
        // Check if regid already presents
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            // Registration is not present, register now with GCM   
            Log.i("LOG", "p1");
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
        } else {

            // Device is already registered on GCM
            if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
                Log.i("LOG", "p2");
                // Skips registration.          
                //GCMRegistrar.unregister(this);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Log.i("LOG", "p3");
                // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
                // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
                // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
                final Context context = this;
                mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // Register on our server
                        // On server creates a new user
                        ServerUtilities.register(context, name, email, regId);

                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        mRegisterTask = null;
                    }

                };
                Log.i("LOG", "pre execute");
                mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
            }
        }
    }       

    /**
     * Receiving push messages
     * */
    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

            /**
             * Take appropriate action on this message
             * depending upon your app requirement
             * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
             * */

            // Showing received message
            lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");           
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Releasing wake lock
            WakeLocker.release();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mRegisterTask != null) {
            mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
        }
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
            GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

activity for register:

```
public final class ServerUtilities {
    private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5;
    private static final int BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS = 2000;
    private static final Random random = new Random();

    /**
     * Register this account/device pair within the server.
     *
     */
    static void register(final Context context, String name, String email, final String regId) {

        Log.i("LOG", "reg p1");
        Log.i(TAG, "registering device (regId = " + regId + ")");
        String serverUrl = SERVER_URL;
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("regId", regId);
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("email", email);

        long backoff = BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS + random.nextInt(1000);
        // Once GCM returns a registration id, we need to register on our server
        // As the server might be down, we will retry it a couple
        // times.
        for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Attempt #" + i + " to register");
            try {
                displayMessage(context, context.getString(
                        R.string.server_registering, i, MAX_ATTEMPTS));
                post(serverUrl, params);
                GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);
                String message = context.getString(R.string.server_registered);
                CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
                return;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Here we are simplifying and retrying on any error; in a real
                // application, it should retry only on unrecoverable errors
                // (like HTTP error code 503).
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to register on attempt " + i + ":" + e);
                if (i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Sleeping for " + backoff + " ms before retry");
                    Thread.sleep(backoff);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // Activity finished before we complete - exit.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Thread interrupted: abort remaining retries!");
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    return;
                }
                // increase backoff exponentially
                backoff *= 2;
            }
        }
        String message = context.getString(R.string.server_register_error,
                MAX_ATTEMPTS);
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Unregister this account/device pair within the server.
     */
    static void unregister(final Context context, final String regId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "unregistering device (regId = " + regId + ")");
        String serverUrl = SERVER_URL + "/unregister";
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("regId", regId);
        try {
            post(serverUrl, params);
            GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, false);
            String message = context.getString(R.string.server_unregistered);
            CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // At this point the device is unregistered from GCM, but still
            // registered in the server.
            // We could try to unregister again, but it is not necessary:
            // if the server tries to send a message to the device, it will get
            // a "NotRegistered" error message and should unregister the device.
            String message = context.getString(R.string.server_unregister_error,
                    e.getMessage());
            CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Issue a POST request to the server.
     *
     * @param endpoint POST address.
     * @param params request parameters.
     *
     * @throws IOException propagated from POST.
     */
    private static void post(String endpoint, Map<String, String> params)
            throws IOException {    

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(endpoint);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid url: " + endpoint);
        }
        StringBuilder bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = params.entrySet().iterator();
        // constructs the POST body using the parameters
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, String> param = iterator.next();
            bodyBuilder.append(param.getKey()).append('=')
                    .append(param.getValue());
            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                bodyBuilder.append('&');
            }
        }
        String body = bodyBuilder.toString();
        Log.v(TAG, "Posting '" + body + "' to " + url);
        byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            Log.e("URL", "> " + url);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            // post the request
            OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
            out.write(bytes);
            out.close();
            // handle the response
            int status = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (status != 200) {
              throw new IOException("Post failed with error code " + status);
            }
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
      }
}
```

and this is the service:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Log.i("LOG", "service created");
    };
    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device registered
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i("LOG", "register service p1");
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
        Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);
        ServerUtilities.register(context, MainActivity.name, MainActivity.email, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device un registred
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        Log.i("LOG", "Unregister service p1");
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Receiving a new message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on receiving a deleted message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Error
     * */
    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        // log message
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
                errorId));
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old tutorial which uses an obsolete class (GCMRegistrar). The recommended method to register to GCM is by the `register` method of `GoogleCloudMessaging` class, which is part of the Google Play Services library. This method is synchroneous and should be run in the background (not in the main thread).

This is unlike the obsolete `GCMRegister.register` method, which is asynchroneous (Google returns the response in the intent service `onRegistered` method).

You should refer to the code samples in the [offical guide](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) and the [official demo](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/DemoActivity.java).

Comment: @Kenji yes. I included links in my answer